# PHP Register not working correctly

Tags: php, sql

I have an error with a PHP register page I am creating.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($username < 6 || $password < 6){
        echo 'The username must be longer than 5 characters';   
    }

    else {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES ('".$username."',MD5('".$password."'))");
    }
}

?>
<form method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" />
<BR>Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="32" />
<BR><input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Whenever I click on submit, even if the username and passwords are longer than 5 characters, it keeps saying the error message.

The page links to the database, but this is just the snippet that I am having trouble with.

Thanks

-Nicholas

Comment: Let me introduce you [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/), before someone introduces him to you in a not so friendly way.

Comment: strlen($username) < 6 || strlen($password) < 6

Comment: lol @ Bobby Tables. Quite useful though. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check if length of username and password is <6 and not $username

```
strlen($username) <6 OR strlen($password) <6
```

Comment: I am pretty new at PHP, would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: @zuc0001 added example for understanding

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the AND operator, not OR?

Comment: no it should be OR only, the questioner wants if any of the username or password is less than 6 then give error.

Comment: Thanks for the OR part too. I'm pretty new at PHP but I'm starting to get the feel for it. Thanks guys :)

Comment: No, it's their bad. Now it sends a warning only if BOTH usernames and passwords are too short.

Comment: @raina77ow ya i edited the comment and code, both. Should be OR only

Comment: I needed it to show a warning if either one is too short. But it works just how I need it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strlen($username) < 6 || strlen($password) < 6){
        echo 'The username must be longer than 5 characters';   
}
```

Please check php string functions in PHP [strlen($username)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)